# Show that $u \in \text{span}(v + w, w + u, u + v)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $u \in \text{span}(v + w, w + u, u + v)$
My first approach is to set the matrix as follows and placing a 1 where a variable exists.

\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&1\\1&0&1&0\\1&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}

reduces down to

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&-1/2\\0&1&0&1/2\\0&0&1&1/2\end{bmatrix}

$a = -\frac{1}{2}, b = \frac{1}{2}, c = \frac{1}{2}$. Now I am lost on justifying on why it spans, because it consists of a trivial solution that is consisent.

Comment: If you don't explain, in particular to yourself, how you form that matrix perhaps you won't be able to understand what is going on...what are the meaning of those numbers there?

Comment: This looks like half a conversation, most of which is going on in your head. How can anyone know what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

$$\frac12(u+w)+\frac12(u+v)-\frac12(v+w)\;\ldots$$

Another way, with matrices, **assuming** $\;u,v,w\;$ **are linearly independent**: denote

$$\begin{cases}&u\leftrightarrow(1,0,0)\\&v\leftrightarrow (0,1,0)\\&w\leftrightarrow (0,0,1)\end{cases}\implies u+v=(1,1,0)\,,\,\,u+w=(1,0,1)\,,\,\,v+w=(0,1,1)$$

Now just check the above last three vectors are *linearly independent* (for example, using a matrix...) and thus obviously $\;u\;$, and any other three dimensional vector,  belongs to their span...

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about showing it as linear independent.